# C++ input / output (getchar)

Tags: c++

```
int show_menu()
{
    std::cout << "\n\n1.Строка\n2.Число\n3.Число с плавающей точкой\n4.Число с плавающей точкой двойной точности\n5.Символ"<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "Введите цифру: ";
    int menu_choice;
    std::cin >> menu_choice;
    return menu_choice;
}

int menu_choice = show_menu();
```

отрывок из main()

```
case 5:
{
    std::cout << "\nВведите символ: ";
    int ch = getchar();
    std::cout << "Вввели: " << ch << "\tРезультат ---> ";
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        std::cout << ((ch >> i) & 1);
    }
    end_work = '-';
    break;
}
```

Консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не очень понимаю, что происходит, почему в переменную ch передаётся результат функции, а не происходит ввод от пользователя. То есть мы в show_menu() в cin ввели к примеру 5 и это же перенеслось в переменную сh. (Как это исправить?)

Comment: *"в cin ввели к примеру 5 и это же перенеслось в переменную сh"* - так оно так и происходит. вы случаем не напутали код символа и число?

Comment: getchar - это сишная функция, а cin - плюсоый объект. Зачем вы пытаетесь комбинировать разные стили ввода-вывода?

Comment: @user7860670 нет, вопрос в том, что я ввожу в функции к примеру '1' и это же передаётся в ch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что после того, как `cin` прочитает число, он оставит в потоке ввода символ новой строки (который Вы создаёте, когда нажимаете Enter после ввода числа). Потом функция `getchar` читает этот символ новой строки (`\n`) и сохраняет результат в переменную `ch`, которая имеет тип `int`. Если заглянуть в [ASCII таблицу](http://www.asciitable.com/), то можно увидеть, что символ новой строки имеет код 10, что Вы и наблюдаете в выводе переменной `ch`. Вы видите именно 10, потому что `ch` имеет тип `int` и `cout` отображает содержимое переменной в виде числа, а не символа.
Чтобы исправить ситуацию, Вам необходимо после ввода числа также прочитать всё до конца строки (т.е. до символа `\n`). Это можно сделать с помощью строки

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Ещё, в виде рекомендации, вместо `getchar()` лучше использовать `cin.get()`.